# How do I change the transition time of an element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, css-transitions

Let's say I have an element with:

```
.element{
/* some css prorieties */
    transition-duration:1.5s;
    transition-delay:.1s;
}
```

Now, triggering it by hovering over another element, I want it to come in with this duration and delay, but go out (not hovering anymore) a little faster.

Now let `bigobj=the object` I hover over

and

let `smallobj=the object` that transitions (`.element`)

My JS looks like this:

```
bigobj.addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
       smallobj.style.transitionDuration=.3;
       smallobj.style.transitionDelay=.3;
});
```

It doesn't work.

If I change it to:

```
smallobj.style.transition="none";
```

it works as intended.

What would be a fix?

Comment: You have to specify a unit; whether `ms` (milliseconds) or `s` (seconds), so the value has to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

First of all sorry for answering a bit late.
Look, everything is perfect in your code except for the value you gave for transitionDelay.

In your code its: `smallobj.style.transitionDelay=.3;`
which should be written with single/double quotes:

`smallobj.style.transitionDelay='.3s';`

> '' and s for seconds is a must for transitionDelay.I hope it works.